# Add or Changing the existing Banners in Broadleaf site

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I Have Tried To Change the banner in heat clinic site. i have tried to replace the existing banner with same name as previous banner. I Want to know How to change the Banners in Broadleaf site.
Please help to solve the issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have already and what happened when you tried.

Comment: I have not done any modifications on the code i just replaced the existing banner with new banner with same name as old banner these banner files files are there in broadleaf core